# How to subset a raster by cell number in R?

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to subset a raster based on cell numbers. I want to provide a vector of cell numbers and return a raster with the original cell values for those cells referenced in the cell numbers vector. I tried the `rasterFromCells()` function but this seems to interpolate between cell numbers and doesn't return values, but rather cell numbers. I've tried:

```
#original raster loaded with 400 sample values ranging from 1:24
foo <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20)
foo[] <- sample(seq(1,24),400,replace = TRUE)
#vector of desired cell numbers
my.pts <- c(2,20,200)
#rasterFromCells attempt
bar<-rasterFromCells(foo, my.pts, values=TRUE)
```

How can I return a raster layer with `foo`'s values for cell numbers 2, 20 and 200 and all other cells as`NA`?

Comment: Which cells do you want the values to go? Is your question about setting all cells that are not at `my.pts` to NA?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Yes, setting all non `my.pts` cells to NA would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a new raster with the values at only the cell locations in `my.pts` replaced by the values at those cell locations in `foo` and all other cell values set to `NA`, you just have to:

1. create a raster (i.e., `bar`) the same size as `foo`.
2. fill it with `NA`s
3. Use `bar[my.pts] <- foo[my.pts]`

For example:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(123) ## for reproducible results
foo <- raster(ncols=20, nrows=20)
foo[] <- sample(seq(1,24),400,replace = TRUE)
#vector of desired cell numbers
my.pts <- c(2,20,200)

## create raster the same size as foo filled with NAs
bar <- raster(ncols=ncol(foo), nrows=nrow(foo))
bar[] <- NA
## replace the values with those in foo
bar[my.pts] <- foo[my.pts]

foo[my.pts]
##[1] 19 23 14

bar[]
##  [1] NA 19 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 23 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
## [32] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
## [63] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
## [94] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[125] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[156] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[187] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[218] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[249] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[280] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[311] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[342] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
##[373] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Another approach to accomplish the same result is to copy `foo` to `bar` and then set all cells locations not in `my.pts` to `NA`s:

```
bar <- foo
bar[setdiff(1:ncell(foo),my.pts)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of `rasterFromCells` is that it returns a smaller raster, as it contains only the cropped version of what you want.

So what you need to do is to feed again the value of your initial raster (*r*) in the new one (*r2*), which is eased by the fact that the new one (*r2*) returns the original cell numbers:

```
r <- raster(ncols=100, nrows=100)
r[] <- rnorm(ncell(r))

cells <- c(3:5, 210)

r2 <- rasterFromCells(r, cells, values=TRUE)
ini_cells <- getValues(r2)
```

Simply feed the values according to the index:

```
r2[] <- r[ini_cells]
```

This results in a raster of 24 cells instead of 10'000!

```
c(ncell(r), ncell(r2))
```

Let us compare the results:

```
data.frame(Orig=getValues(r)[cells], New=getValues(r2)[ini_cells %in% cells])
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.5081512 -0.5081512
[2,] -0.8799739 -0.8799739
[3,]  0.3722788  0.3722788
[4,] -0.7661364 -0.7661364
```

Note: you wanted to set all others to NA. You would do this with:

```
r2[!ini_cells %in% cells] <- NA
head(getValues(r2))
-0.5081512 -0.8799739  0.3722788         NA         NA         NA
```